# MYSQL Select from another column

Tags: mysql

Ok I have two tables. First table is `fmp_leads`. Second table is `sic_codes`

`fmp_leads` has a bunch of lead data, including a column called `sic_code`

`sic_codes` has 3 columns (`id, sic_code, good_bad`)

I want to run this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fmp_leads 
WHERE (
    fmp_leads.sic_code MATCHES sic_codes.sic_code 
    AND sic_codes.good_bad = good
)
```

I realize that statement above isn't real, I'm just not sure how to perform the WHERE statement.

Comment: can you describe all table and show how it looks like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to `JOIN` the two tables `ON` the field you care about and use `=` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM fmp_leads fmp
JOIN sic_codes sic
ON fmp.sic_code = sic.sic_code 
WHERE sic.good_bad = 'good';
```

Comment: Beautiful. I just had to add single quotes around the last 'good'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

well this is another way to get data you want to,

1. fmp_leads  as a
2. sic_codes as b

when you are trying grab data from that table use `where a.sic_code=b.sic_code`

Here is all query

```
select * from fmp_leads a, sic_codes b 
where a.sic_code=b.sic_code and b.good_bad ='good'
```

Note : Just use operator and, or based on you need it and to prevent repeatation using order by id from main table